# Element wise multiplication of two lists

Tags: r, loops, sequence

I have a large data frame and I would like to sequentially multiply two lists of variables to create relevant interactions.

Does someone know how I iterate multiplications across multiple variables sequentially? Ideally using `data.table` or `purrr`

My data looks something like this

```
data(iris)
# I have two lists of variables
sepalvar <- c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")
petalvar <- c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")

#The final dataset should contain Sepal.Length*Petal.Length and a Sepal.Width*Petal.Width interactions. It would look something like this
setDT(iris)[,multlength:=Sepal.Length*Petal.Length
            ][,multwidth:=Sepal.Width*Petal.Width]
head(iris)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species multlength multwidth
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa       7.14      0.70
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa       6.86      0.60
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa       6.11      0.64
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa       6.90      0.62
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa       7.00      0.72
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa       9.18      1.56
```

Is there a way I can iterate this across the two list sequentially creating variables with recognizable names?

thanks a lot in advance for your help

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `mget`to get the values of the objects in a `list` for both 'sepalvar' and 'petalvar', and use `Map` to do the `*` for corresponding elements, and assign (`:=`) it to two new columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(iris)[, c('multlength', 'multwidth')
       := Map(`*`, mget(sepalvar), mget(petalvar))]
```

-output

```
head(iris)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species multlength multwidth
#1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa       7.14      0.70
#2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa       6.86      0.60
#3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa       6.11      0.64
#4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa       6.90      0.62
#5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa       7.00      0.72
#6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa       9.18      1.56
```

---

Or another option is to use `.SD`

```
setDT(iris)[,   c('multlength', 'multwidth') := 
            .SD[, ..sepalvar] * .SD[, ..petalvar]]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this is great! Only one question do I need to specify each name individually? with hundreds of variables it is a lot of typing. is there a way the name of the new variable reflects a combination of the two variables multiplied (e.g using `paste`)?

Comment: @Alex if there are 100s of variable and if there is a pattern in the column name, may be it is better to `melt/pivot_longer` into long format and do the multiplication

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I am not sure a long format would be better as I have thousands of observations. Also, I was wondering is there a reason why you capitalized `Map`?

Comment: @Alex I meant `iris %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(rn, Species),  names_to = c( ".value", "grp"), names_sep = "\\.") %>% transmute(Species, rn, grp, mult = Sepal * Petal) %>% mutate(grp = str_c('mult', grp)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = mult) %>% select(-rn, -Species) %>% bind_cols(iris, .)`

Comment: @Alex the `Map` is from `base R` and it is not the `purrr::map`

Comment: Thanks it works great! I also include the version with paste and `data.table` for future notice `setDT(iris)[, paste((sepalvar),(petalvar),sep="_"):= Map(`*`, mget(sepalvar), mget(petalvar))]`